# check if username is registered android studios json

Tags: java, android, json

I am creating a login / register on android studios with the use of nano and would like to ask how do I check if username is already taken / exist in nanoscale.io.

The code below allows the user to register and account and it will be saved into nanoscale.io. However the user is able to create multiple same usernames. Is there and idea what I can do to prevent that from happening? Thank you!

```
public void signUp(View view) {
        EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerUsername);
        EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.registerPassword);

    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("username", username.getText().toString());
    params.put("password", md5(password.getText().toString()));

    JSONObject parameters = new JSONObject(params); // collect to be sent to web api aka request

    JsonObjectRequest jsonRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, parameters, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
//TODO: handle success
            try {
                finish();

                Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, response.getString("$id").toString() + "Account is registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            error.printStackTrace();
//TODO: handle failure
        }
    });

    Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplication()).add(jsonRequest);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "on android studios with the use of nano" ?